# Hide and Show modal on mouseenter and mouseleave using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I tried adding the condition on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` however the modal is not working but when I tried to create a `button onClick={() => {openModal();}}` the modal will show up. Can you please tell me what's wrong on my code and which part.

```
const openModal = event => {
    if (event) event.preventDefault();
    setShowModal(true);
  };

  const closeModal = event => {
    if (event) event.preventDefault();
    setShowModal(false);
  };

  function useHover() {
    const ref = useRef();
    const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(false);
    const enter = () => setHovered(true);
    const leave = () => setHovered(false);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (ref.current.addEventListener('mouseenter', enter)) {
        openModal();
      } else if (ref.current.addEventListener('mouseleave', leave)) {
        closeModal();
      }
      return () => {
        if (ref.current.addEventListener('mouseenter', enter)) {
          openModal();
        } else if (ref.current.addEventListener('mouseleave', leave)) {
          closeModal();
        }
      };
    }, [ref]);

    return [ref, hovered];
  }

  const [ref, hovered] = useHover();



<div className="hover-me" ref={ref}>hover me</div>

  {hovered && (
    <Modal active={showModal} closeModal={closeModal} className="dropzone-modal">
      <div>content here</div>
    </Modal>
  )}
```

Comment: Are your event function getting triggered on `mouseout` and `mouseenter` ?

Comment: Actually it work on hide and show div example this one `{hovered && <div className="display--this"> hover state</div>}` this will show when the `hover-me` `className` will be hover. But when I tried on modal it doesnt work.

Comment: You should be doing `openModal()` and `closeModal` inside `enter` and `leave` functions.

Comment: What do you mean? would you mind to see a demo if its okay to you.

Comment: Yes please share the working demo

Comment: I mean, can you create a simple demo or a logic instruction.

Comment: Is the modal, when open, blocking the div? Sounds like you're trying to build a tooltip?

Comment: @DrewReese its not a tooltip but a simple modal with a content, just want to show the modal when the hover is happened.

Answer (score 5):

building on [Drew Reese's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60826785/1852456), you can cache the node reference inside the useEffect closure itself, and it simplifies things a bit. You can read more about closures in [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example/).

```js
const useHover = () => {
  const ref = useRef();
  const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(false);
  const enter = () => setHovered(true);
  const leave = () => setHovered(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const el = ref.current; // cache external ref value for use in cleanup
    if (el) {
      el.addEventListener("mouseenter", enter);
      el.addEventListener("mouseleave", leave);

      return () => {
        el.removeEventListener("mouseenter", enter);
        el.removeEventListener("mouseleave", leave);
      };
    }
  }, []);

  return [ref, hovered];
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I almost gave up and passed on this but it was an interesting problem.

**Issues:**

- The first main issue is with the `useEffect` hook of your `useHover` hook, it needs to add/remove **both** event listeners at the same time, when the ref's current component mounts and unmounts. The key part is the hook needs to cache the current ref within the effect hook in order for the cleanup function to correctly function.
- The second issue is you aren't removing the listener in the returned effect hook cleanup function.
- The third issue is that `EventTarget.addEventListener()` returns `undefined`, which is a falsey value, thus your hook never calls `modalOpen` **or** `modalClose`
- The last issue is with the modal open/close state/callbacks being coupled to the `useHover` hook's implementation. (*this is fine, but with this level of coupling you may as well just put the hook logic directly in the parent component, completely defeating the point of factoring it out into a reusable hook!*)

**Solution**

Here's what I was able to get working:

```
const useHover = () => {
  const ref = useRef();
  const _ref = useRef();
  const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(false);
  const enter = () => setHovered(true);
  const leave = () => setHovered(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      _ref.current = ref.current; // cache external ref value for cleanup use
      ref.current.addEventListener("mouseenter", enter);
      ref.current.addEventListener("mouseleave", leave);
    }

    return () => {
      if (_ref.current) {
        _ref.current.removeEventLisener("mouseenter", enter);
        _ref.current.removeEventLisener("mouseleave", leave);
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return [ref, hovered];
};
```

[image: Edit awesome-bardeen-cnqjs]

***Note***: using this with a modal appears to have interaction issues as I suspected, but perhaps your modal works better.

Comment: you can probably cache the current ref inside the useEffect closure. If I could write the code in a comment I would but I put it in [an answer instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66378678/1852456)

Answer (score 0):

one possible reason is when the modal appear, the mouse is focus on the modal => onMouseLeave is trigger => close the modal