# How can i change my spans state using onMouseHover?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, arrow-functions

I am currently changing the state of my span by referring to it using **document.getElementById('heart').innerHTML = 'favorite';**

Is there a better way of doing this? and if so, please share your solution with me. My code is written below.

```
import React from 'react'

//custom  functions
const heartHover = (e)=>{
    document.getElementById('heart').innerHTML = 'favorite';
}
const heartNotHover = (e)=>{
    document.getElementById('heart').innerHTML = 'favorite_border';
}
const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <div>
              <span id="heart" onMouseOver={heartHover} onMouseLeave={heartNotHover} class="material-icons">
                            favorite_border
              </span>
                  
        </div>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use **event listeners** you need **useEffect + clean** them.

Check this solution :
[Hide and Show modal on mouseenter and mouseleave using React Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60824250/hide-and-show-modal-on-mouseenter-and-mouseleave-using-react-hooks)

And this guide :
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-cleanup-event-listeners-react